In mono some winform native components does not display text
At some linux env. mono 6. My code used winform native component(suchFolderBrowserDialog,FontDialog).
When the componment pop up. There is not text on the component's button.
But other custom component ,there are texts on the button.
My env Visual Studio 2015, mono 6.08.
Debian Linux 10.
At some other linux env,it displays normally. And mono version is the same. And linux language and zone setting  which I check is the same too.

With Debian 10 you should use Mono 6.12. Mono is distributed with openSUSE. Might work well enough with Ubuntu 20. Other distributions are not exactly tested

Mono's WinForms has many known issues and it's not clear if the new maintainers will aim to resolve that https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-end-of-mono To be practical you should switch to other cross platform UI frameworks.
